# export matched pairs using MatchIt in r

Tags: r, csv, matching

I need to add a column to `MatchIt` output that defines the matched pairs (i.e. observation with serial number 10 was matched to serial number 23 .etc) and call it 1 and 1 then another pair (eg observation 12 with observation 27.etc).
I want to add the needed column to the matched data and export them in `.csv` using `write.csv(nn.match, file ="matched.data.csv")` so I can do further testing among the matched cohorts as `McNemar test`.

I saw this (https://journals.sfu.ca/jmde/index.php/jmde_1/article/view/431/414) but I could not figure it out till now.

Any way to do that? Appreciate any precious input.

Presuming that this is a sample code:

````
library(MatchIt);library(Matching); data(lalonde)
lalonde$Serial.number <- seq.int(nrow(lalonde))
lalonde.formu <- treat~age + educ + black + hisp + married + nodegr + re74 + re75
### Get matched Data using PSM nearest neighbor
m.nn<-matchit(lalonde.formu, data = lalonde, caliper=0.1, method ="nearest")
nn.match<-match.data(m.nn)
write.csv(nn.match, file ="matched.data.csv")
#============================
#---Outcome analysis    using   paired  t-test
#   this    command saves   the data    matched
matches <- data.frame(m.nn$match.matrix)
#these  commands    find    the matches.    one for group   1   one for group   2
group1  <- match(row.names(matches),    row.names(nn.match))
group2  <- match(matches$X1,    row.names(nn.match))
#   these   commands    extract the outcome value   for the matches
yT      <- nn.match$treat[group1]
yC      <- nn.match$treat[group2]
# binding
matched.cases   <- cbind(matches,   yT, yC)
#Paired t-test
t.test(matched.cases$yT,    matched.cases$yC,   paired  = TRUE)```
````

Comment: If you could [`dput`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/dput) the data that would be helpful to better understand the problem you're facing

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk I tried to use `dput(lalonde)` but it gives me a giant list that I couldn't post here. this data is builtin data. I added the first line in the code so it is easy to see it. Thx a lot.

Comment: can you explain the issue further? is the problem that the t.test is not running or ....?

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk  Thanks for your efforts (upvoted). I just need to add a column to the matched data that has the matched pairs eg 1,1, then ,2,2 then 3,3,..etc. meaning that case number x let say 10 matched to case number 15 then case number 11 matched to case number 17 .etc. This is easy in `SPSS` but I do not know how to get it done in`R`.

Comment: doesn't the `match.matrix` contain the matched control units? after taking a look at the manual of matchit it appears to be the case. do you want to have a df with 10 15 for first row then 11 17 and so on. if so `data.frame(treatement= row.names(m.nn$match.matrix), control=m.nn$match.matrix)` is the solution

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk Thanks for your efforts (upvoted). I tried it and it gives me 2 columns (treatment and X1). I believe that those are the matched pairs which is a great thing, Any idea how to add them to `nn.match` data frame that I got after the match? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Do you want to have both columns bound to the data.frame, by treatment or by control.

Comment: @AbdessabourMtk Thanks for your efforts. Please try to post it as an answer. I want to put 1 and 1 for the 1st matched pair then 2 and 2 for the 2nd matched pair then combine that in a SINGLE column into  `nn.match` so I can do further analysis based on that column.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223381/discussion-between-mohamed-rahouma-and-abdessabour-mtk).

Comment: @Noah Thx a lot. I did minor edits to your code and now it works. code: `match.matrix<-m.nn[["match.matrix"]]
#Getting strata from nearest neighbor matching
nn.match$subclass <- vapply(rownames(nn.match), function(x) {
  out <- which(rownames(match.matrix) == x | apply(match.matrix, 1, function(y) x %in% y))
  if (length(out) == 0) out <- NA_integer_
  out
}, integer(1L))

## To confirm 
cbind(table(nn.match$subclass ))` Appreciate your efforts. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want:

```r
# install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)

tibble(pair.t= as.numeric(row.names(m.nn$match.matrix)), pair.x=as.vector(m.nn$match.matrix)) %>% 
   inner_join(nn.match  %>% mutate(pair.t=row_number()))
#>    pair.t pair.x   age  educ black  hisp married nodegr  re74  re75   re78   u74   u75 treat Serial.number distance weights
#>     <dbl> <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <int>   <int>  <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <int> <int>         <int>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1      1 404       37    11     1     0       1      1     0     0  9930.     1     1     1             1    0.402       1
#>  2      2 355       22     9     0     1       0      1     0     0  3596.     1     1     1             2    0.247       1
#>  3      3 266       30    12     1     0       0      0     0     0 24910.     1     1     1             3    0.559       1
#>  4      4 380       27    11     1     0       0      1     0     0  7506.     1     1     1             4    0.353       1
#>  5      5 207       33     8     1     0       0      1     0     0   290.     1     1     1             5    0.410       1
#>  6      6 357       22     9     1     0       0      1     0     0  4056.     1     1     1             6    0.380       1
#>  7      7 256       23    12     1     0       0      0     0     0     0      1     1     1             7    0.551       1
#>  8      8 245       32    11     1     0       0      1     0     0  8472.     1     1     1             8    0.358       1
#>  9      9 NA        19     9     1     0       0      1     0     0  8174.     1     1     1            11    0.377       1
#> 10     10 NA        21    13     1     0       0      0     0     0 17095.     1     1     1            12    0.531       1
#> # … with 175 more rows

# if you want only the 160 matches
tibble(pair.t= as.numeric(row.names(m.nn$match.matrix)), pair.x=as.vector(m.nn$match.matrix)) %>% 
   inner_join(nn.match  %>% mutate(pair.t=row_number())) %>% na.omit
#>    pair.t pair.x   age  educ black  hisp married nodegr  re74  re75   re78   u74   u75 treat Serial.number distance weights
#>     <dbl> <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <int>   <int>  <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <int> <int>         <int>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#>  1      1 404       37    11     1     0       1      1     0     0  9930.     1     1     1             1    0.402       1
#>  2      2 355       22     9     0     1       0      1     0     0  3596.     1     1     1             2    0.247       1
#>  3      3 266       30    12     1     0       0      0     0     0 24910.     1     1     1             3    0.559       1
#>  4      4 380       27    11     1     0       0      1     0     0  7506.     1     1     1             4    0.353       1
#>  5      5 207       33     8     1     0       0      1     0     0   290.     1     1     1             5    0.410       1
#>  6      6 357       22     9     1     0       0      1     0     0  4056.     1     1     1             6    0.380       1
#>  7      7 256       23    12     1     0       0      0     0     0     0      1     1     1             7    0.551       1
#>  8      8 245       32    11     1     0       0      1     0     0  8472.     1     1     1             8    0.358       1
#>  9     11 281       18     8     1     0       0      1     0     0     0      1     1     1            13    0.393       1
#> 10     12 263       27    10     1     0       1      1     0     0 18740.     1     1     1            14    0.408       1
#> # … with 150 more rows
```

#### explanations:

- `tibble(pair.t= as.numeric(row.names(m.nn$match.matrix)), pair.x=as.vector(m.nn$match.matrix))` creates a `tibble` similar to a data.frame that contains the matches.
- the next line inner joins it with nn.match data.frame after adding a pair.t column that contains the treatment id. they're joined on equal `pair.t`