# PSM: Extracting group from MachIT package in r

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching

I would like to do ttest after MachIt. But I can't extract the group2, using this code: `group2 <- match(matches$X1, row.names(nn.match))`. the vector of group2 is empty after running the code. How can I get the value of this vector. Please see the detail code below that I extracted from a post in here early: [export matched pairs using MatchIt in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64444676/export-matched-pairs-using-matchit-in-r).

Thank you.

R code:

```
library(MatchIt);library(Matching); data(lalonde)
lalonde$Serial.number <- seq.int(nrow(lalonde))
lalonde.formu <- treat~age + educ + black + hisp + married + nodegr + re74 + re75
### Get matched Data using PSM nearest neighbor
m.nn<-matchit(lalonde.formu, data = lalonde, caliper=0.1, method ="nearest")
nn.match<-match.data(m.nn)
write.csv(nn.match, file ="matched.data.csv")
#============================
#---Outcome analysis    using   paired  t-test
#   this    command saves   the data    matched
matches <- data.frame(m.nn$match.matrix)
#these  commands    find    the matches.    one for group   1   one for group   2
group1  <- match(row.names(matches),    row.names(nn.match))
group2  <- match(matches$X1,    row.names(nn.match))
#   these   commands    extract the outcome value   for the matches
yT      <- nn.match$treat[group1]
yC      <- nn.match$treat[group2]
# binding
matched.cases   <- cbind(matches,   yT, yC)
#Paired t-test
t.test(matched.cases$yT,    matched.cases$yC,   paired  = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the vector of treated outcomes to be in the same order as the vector of control outcomes with respect to pair membership (which is in the `subclass` column of the `match.data()` output). What you can do is sort the matched dataset by `subclass`, then extract the outcomes of the treated and the outcomes of the control.

```
#Order the matched dataset by pair ID
nn.match <- nn.match[order(nn.match$subclass),]

#Extract the outcomes for the treated and control
y1 <- nn.match$re78[nn.match$treat == 1]
y0 <- nn.match$re78[nn.match$treat == 0]

#Run the paired t-test
t.test(y1, y0, paired = TRUE)
```

Another error in your code is that you assign `yT` and `yC` as the vector of treatment rather than the vector of outcomes. Nowhere in your code do you include the outcome, `re78`.